# Managing multiple button selectors?

Tags: android, xml, button, css-selectors

My calculator app consists of **30 buttons**. I want to provide themes for the calculator keypad. A theme changes button background **(gradients, not image backgrounds)** and font. Some themes have the same color for all buttons while some have a color for numbers, another color for operators and so on.

The color change is using selectors from res/drawable/*.xml

How do I change the theme via the code?
Hopefully avoiding typing:

`button.setBackground(Drawable background);`

`button.setTypeface(font);` 
 30 times. And if I have 5 themes, then 30 * 5 * 2 = 300 lines of codes!!

I'm new to this and if there is no other way I'll go with the 150 lines.

Also how do I save the user theme selection? Using preferences?

Comment: Why not put it in a function and then loop through all your views and call that function on each one? Possibly reduced to <10 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom XML theme which will change all of your XML components. After creating a new theme, go into the Android Manifest file and change the theme. For example:

```
<activity
android:name="com.myapp.MyActivity"
...
android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme" />
```

To create the theme, go to res/values/themes.xml and create a new theme with an identifier:

```
<resources>
    ...
    <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="android:style/Theme">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffff0000</item>
    </style>
    ...
</resources>
```

By using this method, you can create an extensive library of different themes and change to what theme you want.

**NOTE**: This is not just for changing the background, but it can also be used to change the theme of the buttons. Visit this website for more information:

http://janrain.com/blog/introduction-to-android-theme-customization/

**EDIT**: As that user commented, it is possible that you can put the function to change the theme of the button in a `for()` loop.

For your case, I have derived this from the link above. It will change the texture of the buttons in your XML file rather than in Java.

"Using a Custom Nine-Patch With Buttons

A nine-patch drawable is a special kind of image which can be scaled in width and height while maintaining its visual integrity. Nine-patches are the most common way to specify the appearance of Android buttons, though any drawable type can be used.

Example nine-patch PNG.

Notice the one pixel black lines around the edge, they control the scaling of the image.

Save this bitmap as MyApplication/res/drawable/my_nine_patch.9.png
Define a new style (you can define the new style in the same file that you defined your custom theme from Creating a Custom Android Theme above) …:

```
<resources>
   ...
       <style name="MyCustomButton" parent="android:Widget.Button">
           <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_nine_patch</item>
       </style>
   ...
</resources>
```

Apply the new button style to the buttonStyle attribute of your custom theme:

```
<resources>
   ...
       <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent=...>
           ...
           <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyCustomButton</item>
       </style>
   ...
</resources>
```

Now the buttons in the activities your theme is applied to have custom images. However, you may notice that they don’t change appearance when selected. Read Selector Drawables below for an introduction to using multiple drawables to define one drawable that changes based on state."

From here, you can change certain components of the theme (such as the button texture as an image).

After you have a theme that looks good, apply it in the Android Manifest as I mentioned above.

I will FURTHER edit this if it still does not answer your question.

Comment: Yes it does not answer my question. I see we're creating styles but I don't see how that can be used to apply background for buttons.

Comment: Thank you. I can take it from here.